# Text appearing and bold selected link CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to open an eBay store and I need help to create a graphic for my insertions using HTML and CSS (not JavaScript).

More specifically, I want to create a menu with `<ul></ul>` with "Description", "Shipping" etc. By pressing the "Description" link I'll see some text appear and "Description" label will get bold, then if I click on "Shipping" menu the previous text disappears and another text appears. I was able to do each thing separately on two different CSS styles using `:target`:

Code 1:

```css
#menu_descrizione:target{
    font-weight: bold;
}

#menu_spedizione:target{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<a id="menu_descrizione" href="#menu_descrizione">Descrizione</a>
<a id="menu_spedizione" href="#menu_spedizione">Spedizione</a>
```

Code 2:

```css
#descrizione, #spedizione{
   display: none;
}

#descrizione:target{
    display: block;
}

#spedizione:target{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#descrizione">Descrizione</a>
<a href="#spedizione">Spedizione</a>

<p id="descrizione">Questa è una descrizione</p>
<p id="spedizione">Questa è una spedizione</p>
```

[Fiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/8qp9yogy/)
[Fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/yzayw36b/)

How can I unite these effects into one?

Comment: While dippas has provided an answer, I would suggest that you try and produce this functionality with JavaScript. It's what it is built for, and will be much more useful for you if your site becomes more complicated or if you actually want to *do* something with the data

Comment: @JackParkinson thank you, where can I find dippas's answer?

Comment: Oh, it appears it has been deleted - looks like maybe it wasn't a good answer after all.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to do this with javascript.

Here is your HTML
I've added 2 classes called btn.

```
<a href="#descrizione"  class="btn">Descrizione</a>
<a href="#spedizione" class="btn">Spedizione</a>

<p id="descrizione">Questa è una descrizione</p>
<p id="spedizione">Questa è una spedizione</p>
```

Here is your CSS

```
#descrizione, #spedizione{
    display: none;
}

#descrizione:target{
    display: block;
}
```

And here is some jQuery

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
    $(".btn").not(this).css("font-weight","normal");
})
```

And [here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/leagz/yzayw36b/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much!